# body of report not visible

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, reporting-services-2012

Using Visual Studio 2015 mvc 5 application.  I have created an `SSRS report` with Visual Studio 2012 that does not take any parameters (yet).  I used `nuget` to add `ReportViewerForMvc`.  I went through an online tutorial to create `ReportTemplate.aspx` etc.  I'm using Forms Authentication so I changed my data sources to use a static SQL Login in `SSRS`.  When I run the report manually I get 151 pages.  When I run it through the application the toolbar at the top reads 1 of 151 pages.  However,  I can't see the body of the report and all the buttons on the toolbar are disabled.  I've been fiddling with the control properties in the `ReportTemplate.aspx.cs` (code behind) and the `ReportTemplate.aspx`  but nothing seems to change it.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            try
            {
                String reportFolder = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SSRSReportFolder"].ToString();
                String reportUri = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SSRSReportUri"].ToString();

                rvSiteMapping.Height = Unit.Pixel(2000);
                rvSiteMapping.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode.Remote;

                rvSiteMapping.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(reportUri); // Add the Reporting Server URL 
                rvSiteMapping.ServerReport.ReportPath = String.Format("/{0}/{1}", reportFolder, Request["ReportName"].ToString());
                rvSiteMapping.ServerReport.Timeout = 320000;

                rvSiteMapping.ServerReport.Refresh();

                rvSiteMapping.ShowReportBody = true;
                rvSiteMapping.ShowToolBar = true;
                rvSiteMapping.SizeToReportContent = true;
                rvSiteMapping.Enabled = true;
                rvSiteMapping.Visible = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Write(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Package Entries:

```
<package id="MicosoftReportViewerWebForms_v11" version="1.0.1" targetFramework="net451" />
<package id="ReportViewerForMvc" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net451" />
```

Web.Config:

```
<httpHandlers>
    <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" validate="false" />
</httpHandlers>
```

...

```
<handlers>
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
    <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
    <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
</handlers>
```

Thanks
Lee

Comment: ...just for good measure perhaps can you place all the sizing and configuration settings before refresh and have refresh be the last call made.

Comment: Yeah.  I've tried that already.  That is how it is setup by default in the demo, I moved it after the refresh just for grins.  It didn't seem to affect anything either way.  I also have similar settings in the aspx

Comment: <rsweb:ReportViewer  runat ="server" 
              ShowPrintButton="true"  
              ShowParameterPrompts="true"
              ShowToolBar="true"
              Enabled ="true"
              Width="1200px" Height="1200px" 
              AsyncRendering="false" 
              KeepSessionAlive="true" 
              id="rvSiteMapping" 
              SizeToReportContent="true" 
              ShowCredentialPrompts="true"
              ShowReportBody="true"> 
        </rsweb:ReportViewer>

Comment: Just realized that the script is giving an error message in the browser.

Comment: Baby Steps.  When I tracked through the first error on the list I found that the script was referencing the control named "ReportViewer1" although I'd given the control the name ivScriptMapping (that came from the demo I was following)  once I changed the id to Reportviewer1 now the toolbar is enabled.  I can export the report to pdf and it looks fine.  I still can't see the report on the screen, like a preview as you expect to.